# Как установить пакет для Node.js через прокси?

Tags: node.js, windows, прокси

Устанавливают websocket'ы через прокси командой

```
npm install websocket-server
```

В ответ ошибка:

> `npm ERR! Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT`.

Пробовал так:

```
npm --proxy http://сервер:порт/ install websocket-server
```

То же самое. Как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ.

```
set HTTP_PROXY=сервер:порт
npm install websocket-server
```